# A script to draw, fill and group triangles in Livecode?

Tags: polygon, livecode

Appreciate any help in coming up with a Livecode script chunk to draw and fill a group of equilateral triangles.

I'm working on an open source app that helps people create and share stories with a fractal pattern.

A key challenge is drawing triangles that will represent the following elements of a story:

- Attractor
- Challenge
- Opportunity (a state change to resolve the tension)
- Strategy
- Test
- Decision

Each of the six standard story elements above will be displayed in the app as an equilateral triangle. Each element, in turn, will be associated with a  distinctive color – yellow, red, orange, purple, blue, or green.

I'd love for a Livecode script to draw six triangles that fit together – much like pie slices – to form a hexagon that represents the whole narrative.

The transparency (blendlevel) of each colored segment will indicate the degree to which the story's author(s) – or invited reviewers – consider that element of the story to be complete.

My hope is to come up with a script in Livecode that will:

- rapidly draw six triangles to form a hexagonal shape
- fill each triangle with its associated color (each color will have an initial blendlevel of an almost transparent 90 percent)
- assign a unique short name to each of the six triangles, based on the name of its fill color
- group the six triangles so that they can be dragged together to new locations on the screen.

Are there any scripts (or chunks) that can help on this?  Deeply appreciate any sample code or links to help shorten my Livecode learning curve.

Best,

Mark Frazier

====== Progress Update! ======  [August 2nd, 6 pm Eastern]

I've just found and adapted a polygon-generating script by Lloyd Rieber of Univ. of Georgia that creates hexagons. Is there a way to tweak it, so that it can create an equilateral triangle that can then be copied and rotated to fill out the hexagon?

```
on mouseUp
global tpoints
if exists(grc "HexagonCanvas" of this card) then delete grc "HexagonCanvas"
lock screen
create grc "HexagonCanvas" 
set the loc of grc "HexagonCanvas" to "140,140"
set the opaque of grc "HexagonCanvas" to true
-- resize the new grc
get the rect of grc "HexagonCanvas" 
add 80 to item 4 of it
set the rect of grc "HexagonCanvas" to it
put the topleft of grc "HexagonCanvas" into TL
put the topright of grc "HexagonCanvas" into TR
put the bottomleft of grc "HexagonCanvas" into BL
put the bottomright of grc "HexagonCanvas" into BR
put the width of grc "HexagonCanvas" into twidth
put the height of grc "HexagonCanvas" into theight
put trunc(twidth/4) into twidthquart
put trunc(theight/2) into theighthalf
#=========set the points for the "free" hexagon polygon==================
put empty into tpoints
put (item 1 of TL + twidthquart, item 2 of TL) into tpoints
# for the first line of tpoints "put into"
put Cr& (item 1 of TL, item 2 of TL + theighthalf) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of BL + twidthquart, item 2 of BL) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of BR - twidthquart, item 2 of BR) after tpoints
put Cr& (item 1 of BR, item 2 of BR - theighthalf) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of TR - twidthquart, item 2 of TR) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of TL + twidthquart, item 2 of TL) after tpoints
set the points of grc "HexagonCanvas" to tpoints
set the style of grc "HexagonCanvas" to "polygon"
set the backgroundColor of grc "HexagonCanvas" to blue
set the blendlevel of grc "HexagonCanvas" to "60"
choose browse tool
end mouseUp
```

Comment: I have added code below which draws 6 triagles. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part of this is drawing on the fly. You can certainly write a routine that will create your hexagonal pie, but it is better to draw this once and simply show or hide it.

The thing itself will be a group of six triangles, each of which can be addressed and have its properties set, color, blendLevel, etc.

If you need multiple copies of this gadget, you can clone the group, and rename both it and its triangle components at will.

One caveat. If you do proceed in this way, you must be aware that, for groups alone among all object classes, the keyword "last" is not stable. So your ability to reference this new group (set the name of the last group to "yourNewGroupname") is limited in that way. There is a workaround, using the template group, however, that works just fine. I recommend that you read the user notes in the dictionary under "last":

----The "last" keyword is not stable when referring to groups. So if one creates several groups, referencing the "last" group may not return the group actually created last. Using the "templateGroup" is a workaround, since when creating a new group one can, for example, set the name of the templateGroup to something unique, and be able to find the last group by name. Also, trapping the "newGroup" message with an appropriate script can be used to find the last group.

Hope this helps...

EDIT.

Are you familiar with the pertinent properties? The "backColor" to set the color, the "blendLevel" to set, well, the blendLevel, etc? Have you ever created a graphic like a triangle, and named it? Have you ever grouped objects?

Comment: When isn't it stable?

Comment: It's hard to rely on the "last" identifier with groups. Mostly when working with groups that are in other groups, or when they're being relayered by the engine automatically (for example after using "stop editing <group>").

Comment: Craig, many thanks for your insights. So far, I've managed to draw a hexagon with the following script – 

 on mouseUp
   choose line tool
   set the dragSpeed to 0
   drag from 200,200 to 300,267
   drag from 300,267 to 300,367
   drag from 300,367 to 200,433
drag from 200,433 to 100,367
drag from 100,367 to 100,267
 drag from 100,267 to 200,200
    choose browse tool
end mouseUp

But I don't see how to name and save the new graphic as a polygon, so I can do the rest:
 --    set the backgroundColor of grc "HexagonCanvas" to blue
   -- set the blendlevel of grc "HexagonCanvas" to "60"

Comment: (cont) I'm hoping next to try a similar script that creates an equilateral triangle - a triangle that can be copied six times (around the hexagon's center in 60 degree increments) in line with the edges of the hexagon.

Answer (score 0):

**Reference**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle

**Iteration step**

I took the script you found and with some light tweaks it works nicely. There is a

```
polygon polygonName, px, py, pColor
```

script which is called 4 times by a mouse up script. It draws 4 hexagons in different colors.

The polygon script does not live up to its name as it can only draw hexagons.

And then a mouseup script which uses the triangle script six times.

```
on mouseup
   polygon "hex1", 100, 300, "green"
   polygon "hex2", 240, 300, "yellow"
   polygon "hex3", 380, 300, "red"
   polygon "hex4", 520, 300, "brown"
end mouseup

on polygon polygonName, px, py, pColor
   global tpoints
   local TL
   local TR
   local BL
   local BR
   local twidth
   local theight
   local twidthquart
   local theighthalf
if exists(grc polygonName of this card) then delete grc polygonName
lock screen
create grc polygonName 

set the loc of grc polygonName to px,py 

set the opaque of grc polygonName to true
-- resize the new grc
get the rect of grc polygonName 
add 80 to item 4 of it
set the rect of grc polygonName to it
put the topleft of grc polygonName into TL
put the topright of grc polygonName into TR
put the bottomleft of grc polygonName into BL
put the bottomright of grc polygonName into BR
put the width of grc polygonName into twidth
put the height of grc polygonName into theight
put trunc(twidth/4) into twidthquart
put trunc(theight/2) into theighthalf
#=========set the points for the "free" hexagon polygon==================
put empty into tpoints
put (item 1 of TL + twidthquart, item 2 of TL) into tpoints
# for the first line of tpoints "put into"
put Cr& (item 1 of TL, item 2 of TL + theighthalf) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of BL + twidthquart, item 2 of BL) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of BR - twidthquart, item 2 of BR) after tpoints
put Cr& (item 1 of BR, item 2 of BR - theighthalf) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of TR - twidthquart, item 2 of TR) after tpoints
put CR& (item 1 of TL + twidthquart, item 2 of TL) after tpoints
set the points of grc polygonName to tpoints
set the style of grc polygonName to "polygon"
set the backgroundColor of grc polygonName to pColor
set the blendlevel of grc polygonName to "60"
choose browse tool
end polygon
```

**Next iteration step**

To continue various ways are possible.

An easy to follow way would be to modify the polygon script so that it works on triangles instead of a hexagon. As parameters it needs the position of the triangle (following a "clock dial convention or giving the sector in degrees)

Coordinates

```
                  (-r/2 ,h)                (r/2,h)




      -r/0                      0                        r/ 0




                  (-r/2 ,h)                (r/2,h)
```

r = radius
h = height

h*h + (r/2)*(r/2) = r*r

Code which draws six triangles

`

```
on mouseUp
   global tOffset
   put 140 into tOffset
   triangle "triangle1", -50,100, 0,0, -100, 0, "red"
   triangle "triangle2", 0,0,  -50, 100, 50,100, "green"
   triangle "triangle3", 50, 100,  100, 0, 0,0, "blue"
   triangle "triangle4", 0, 0,  100, 0, 50, -100, "yellow"
   triangle "triangle5", 0, 0,  50, -100, -50, -100, "orange"
   triangle "triangle6", 0, 0,  -50, -100, -100, 0, "purple"
end mouseUp


on triangle polygonName, pax, pay, pbx, pby, pcx, pcy, pColor

   global tpoints
   global tOffset

   if exists(grc polygonName of this card) then delete grc polygonName

   lock screen

   create grc polygonName 
   set the loc of grc polygonName to pax,pay 
   set the opaque of grc polygonName to true

   put empty into tpoints

   put (tOffset+pax, tOffset+pay) into tpoints

   put Cr& (tOffset+pbx, tOffset+pby) after tpoints

   put Cr& (tOffset+pcx, tOffset+pcy) after tpoints

   set the points of grc polygonName to tpoints

   set the style of grc polygonName to "polygon"
   set the backgroundColor of grc polygonName to pColor
   set the blendlevel of grc polygonName to "20"

   choose browse tool
end triangle
```

**Wiki**

I made this a community wiki answer, so that people can easily paste in updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Very industrious. Really.

I meant to create a triangle graphic using the polygon tool. You can set the number of sides of the graphic to 3 and name it, say "t1". You may have to adjust it to appear as an equilateral. This is now a full fledged object, and can be duplicated five times. Each new object can be named accordingly, ("t2", "t3", etc) and rotated so that you can assemble them all into a nice hexagon.

Now you can set the backColor and blendLevel of each graphic as you wish. Make sure that each graphic has its "opaque" property set to "true". If you group the six, you can clone new groups, but you have to manage the names of the offspring triangles.

Back to your earlier effort. You can see that even if you created a nice graphic using lines, there would be no easy way to isolate individual triangular sections. The polygon object fixes this nicely.

Craig