# Is there a turtle graphic implementation for LC?

Tags: graphics, livecode, turtle-graphics

How can I do turtle graphics in LiveCode?

I assume somebody probably already has some scripts.

**References**

- This question is related to 
  [A script to draw, fill and group triangles in Livecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996374/a-script-to-draw-fill-and-group-triangles-in-livecode)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make them yourself, but they're easy. This is a simple example. You'll have to adjust a few things to make it a real turtle thing.

```
on foo theNumOfSteps
   if there is an img 1 then delete img 1
   put the width of this cd / theNumOfSteps into x
   put the height of this cd / theNumOfSteps into y
   choose line tool
   repeat with z = 1 to theNumOfSteps
      drag from 0,y*z to x*z,the height of this cd
   end repeat
   choose browse tool
end foo
```

Comment: Thank you. This is useful for a start. Additional small question: How do I set the color of the line?

Comment: set the penColor to blue